# Adding projects with dependencies to solution (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies, project-management

So currently we are in a situation where we have acquired quite a large code base. Every once in a while we start new projects (new Visual Studio Solutions) that require parts of our already existing code base. 
Now the tedious part begins once you add one of these projects to the new Solution because this project requires other project files that it depends on (which in-tern again require different other projects).

So my question is:
Is there an easy way in visual studio to tell it to crawl a certain folder for these missing dependencies? So that it loads all the respective .proj files into my solution that it requires?
This sounds like such an obvious thing to me that I am certain there must be a better way?

Thanks a lot in advance
Oli

Comment: Do you really need to include these projects as source code? Maybe, you'll build them separately (as a some sort of framework) and include them as a nuget package(s), deployed on your own nuget server?

Comment: All these projects are constantly evolving. So yes, I would like to add them as source code.
I don't see why that should be so hard for Visual Studio? I mean it already knows the ID of the missing dependency. If I pass it the folder location of our SVN repository it should be able to crawl all .proj files for the matching dependency (and do this recursively) right ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No, to this day I have not...

Comment: What Dennis said is completely possible, you can keep a repository for that massive code base you acquired, and deployed them as nuget packages or having a shared assemblies folder (within a version control system) thus you can evolve them while adding 'em to your solutions. Also, you can build your own Load Manager (like this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kolomiets.SolutionLoadManager) with this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh966591.aspx and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891035/easy-way-to-add-multiple-existing-csproj-to-a-visual-studio-solution)