# How can I get a full path of a given path (can be a directory or file, or even full path) using C#?

Tags: c#, path, .net, filesysteminfo

The closest I get is using `new FileInfo(path).FullPath`, but as far as I know FileInfo is for files only, not directory.

<sup>See also my comments to [Jon Skeet's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703281/getting-path-relative-to-the-current-working-directory/703290#703290) for context.</sup>

Comment: Add some examples. It's not clear what you want.

Comment: Indeed context may prove my answer to be not what your looking for

Comment: @@LouisRhys - What exactly is your question?  The linked question does not tell me what you are looking for.  You should be using **FileSystemInfo** and determine if its a File or a Directory.  You keep trying to find faults in the provided answers without explaining the reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Path class also gives you a lot of nice methods and properties, e.g. GetFullPath(). See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) for all details.

Answer (score 2):

[P`ath.GetFullPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) class for paths to directories. Works much in the same matter as FileInfo.

Note that the property for the path is called FullName.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Foo\Bar\");
string path = di.FullName;
```

If you want to determine whether a path is a file or a directory, you can use static methods from the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class:

```
string path1 = @"C:\Foo\Bar.docx";
string path2 = @"C:\Foo\";

bool output1 = Path.HasExtension(path1); //Returns true
bool output2 = Path.HasExtension(path2); //Returns false
```

However, paths could also contain something that might resemble an extension, so you might want to use it in conjunction with some other checks, e.g. `bool isFile = File.Exists(path);`

Comment: what if it's a file, not directory?

Comment: You really need to distinguish between when you want the path for a directory or when you want the path for a file. As far as I know, there is no generic "Path" class, to represent either a file or a directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file.getdirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa253319%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's-

```
DirectoryInfo.FullName
```

Comment: what if it's a file, not directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String strYourFullPath = "";
IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strYourFullPath)
```

Comment: It doesn't return the full path

Comment: It does. when strYourFullPath is a file, then it returns the directory where it file is in, when its strYourFullPath is a directory, its stays the same. If this is not what you are looking for, then what are you trying to achive?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DirectoryInfo` class which extends `FileSystemInfo` and will give the correct result for either files or directories.

```
        string path = @"c:\somefileOrDirectory";
        var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        var fullPath = directoryInfo.FullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx), `FileSystemInfo.FullName` gets the full path of the **directory or file**, and [can be applied](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_properties.aspx) to a `FileInfo`.

```
FileInfo fi1 = new FileInfo(@"C:\someFile.txt");
Debug.WriteLine(fi1.FullName); // Will produce C:\someFile.txt
FileInfo fi2 = new FileInfo(@"C:\SomeDirectory\");
Debug.WriteLine(fi2.FullName); // Will produce C:\SomeDirectory\
```

Comment: FileSystemInfo is an abstract class, I cannot do new FileSystemInfo(path).FullPath

Comment: @LouisRhys: Did you try `FileInfo(path).FullName`?

Comment: @LouisRhys - Why do you need to have a **FileSystemInfo** variable exactly? **FullPath** or **FullName** returns a **String**.  **new FileSystemInfo(path).FullPath** makes no sense