# Absolute to Relative path

Tags: c#, path

I'm getting a file from an OpenFileDialog which returns a string with the absolute path to the selected file. Now I want that path as a relative path to a given path (in this case the path to my application).

So let's say I get a path to the file:
`c:\myDock\programming\myProject\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs`

and my application is located in

`c:\myDock\programming\otherProject\bin\Debug\program.exe`

then I want the result:

`..\..\..\myProject\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs`

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23697173/64334

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `Uri` class has a [`MakeRelativeUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.makerelativeuri.aspx) method that can help.

```
public static string MakeRelative(string filePath, string referencePath)
{
    var fileUri = new Uri(filePath);
    var referenceUri = new Uri(referencePath);
    return Uri.UnescapeDataString(referenceUri.MakeRelativeUri(fileUri).ToString()).Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
}

var result = MakeRelative(@"C:\dirName\dirName2\file.txt", @"C:\dirName\");
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I was editing my answer as you were commenting ;)

Comment: Its all right, the link which I posted will be helpful for others too.

Comment: Thx for the link edit ^^

Comment: Technically, to have the path with backslashes, you should add `.Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)` behind the `.ToString()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's nice to see constructive comments that add value to the answer after 2 years :)

Comment: This does not handle all edge cases. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path/32113484#32113484) answer.

Comment: This fails if the filename contains characters that have to be URL encoded (e.g. spaces), you need to add Uri.UnescapeDataString

Comment: This only works if the referencePath is a directory ending with a directory separator.