# C# Relative Filepath

Tags: c#, relative-path

With the absolute path stated below, how can I convert it to be a relative path?

```
System.IO.FileInfo path = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\MassSpecStudio\MassSpecStudio 2.0\source\MassSpecStudio\Core\app.config");
```

My initial attempt was

```
System.IO.FileInfo path = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"..\..\..\..\..\MassSpecStudio\MassSpecStudio 2.0\source\MassSpecStudio\Core\app.config");
```

but this path cannot be found so I guess my attempt is incorrect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute to Relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266756/absolute-to-relative-path)

Comment: Relative to my C drive.

Comment: You're sure about your current path? Try to use `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` to see your working directory.

Comment: It occurred to me your question's actually a bit ambiguous. Do you want to know how to get C# to do the conversion, or are you asking how you can do it yourself? If so, I suspect what you REALLY want is `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),"GitHub\MassSpecStudio\[etc..]")`

Comment: relative path come with respect to some file for process. maybe you are trying to access app.config related to "yourapplication.exe" file then put related path related to that exe. (ex : app is  MassSpecStudio\app\app.exe then "..\..\core\app.config")

Comment: The GetCurrentDirectory states that my working directory is at
C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\MassSpecStudio\MassSpecStudio 2.0\Output\bin