# To relative path from base absolute

Tags: c#, .net, path, directory

I have an absolute folder path and files path like following:

`C:\BaseDir` - *base folder*

`C:\BaseDir\sub\123.txt` - path to file that is located in *base folder* (but maybe also with some subfolders)

Another example of file path: `C:\BaseDir\file.docx` or `C:\BaseDir\sub\sub1\file.exe`

I need to convert pathes to files from absolute to relative based on the *base folder*. Results should look like following:
`sub\123.txt` ; `file.docx` ; `sub\sub1\file.exe`

Please note, that I don't want `BaseDir` in path. Solution should also work with network folders(`\\Server1\BaseDir\file.docx` or `\\172.31.1.60\BaseDir\sub\123.txt`).

Are there any built in classes that do this?

Comment: I would try with Substring & IndexOf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute to Relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266756/absolute-to-relative-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits goes do this post: [Absolute to Relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266756/absolute-to-relative-path#)

```
public static string AbsoluteToRelativePath(string pathToFile, string referencePath)
{
    var fileUri = new Uri(pathToFile);
    var referenceUri = new Uri(referencePath);
    return referenceUri.MakeRelativeUri(fileUri).ToString();
}
```

Now you can use this like

```
var result = AbsoluteToRelativePath(@"C:\dir\path\to\file.txt", @"C:\dir\");
```

Comment: It does not work!
E.g.: filepath="c:\a\b.txt", the basepath="c:\x", then I expect the result: "..\a\b.txt". But it has different result.
*EDIT:* sorry, it works, but basepath must end with "\", so "c:\x\"

Answer (score 1):

There is another option when using .NET Core 2 or newer:

```
var basePath = @"C:\BaseDir\";
var path = @"C:\BaseDir\sub\file.docx";
var relative = Path.GetRelativePath(basePath, path);
```

The difference (might an advantage) to `Uri` is, that the path gets not escaped. When using `Uri`, spaces gets replaced by `%20` etc.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [`MakeRelativeUri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.makerelativeuri(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var basePath = @"C:\BaseDir\";
var path = @"C:\BaseDir\sub\file.docx";
var result = new Uri(basePath).MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(path));
Console.WriteLine(Uri.UnescapeDataString(result.ToString()));
```