# Getting a directory path using project directory

Tags: c#, path

I have a project whose name is **Myproject.Application.DataExporter**. I'm saving a file to a directory whose name is **Export**. I'm using this code :

```
workbook.Save(@"D:\workspace\MyApp\Myproject.Application.DataExporter\Export\Calc.xlsx");
```

I see how to get current project directory in Stackoverflow. There is this code :

```
Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
```

I want to save file under **Export** directory, using a generic path like the code above. It gives current project directory. I want to use it for adding a file to **Export** directory. How can I use it in my project for adding a file to Export? Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate your question - what does it mean _I don't know how to use this code in my project?_ What is your current code? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Assign it to a variable or pass it to a method like anything else? I believe the question needs some more clarification as to what you actually need help with.

Comment: @PawełHemperek I edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string dir = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
string path = Path.Combine(dir, "Myproject.Application.DataExporter", "Export");
string file = "Calc.xlsx";
workbook.Save(Path.Combine(path, file));
```

or if you want to skip `Myproject.Application.DataExporter`

```
string dir = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
string path = Path.Combine(dir, "Export");
string file = "Calc.xlsx";
workbook.Save(Path.Combine(path, file));
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the other previous comments you need to clarify your question.  I'm assuming you want to get the current directory and then save a file to it so the path is relative to where you host your application?

You could just do this:

```
workbook.Save(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Calc.xlsx");
```

To get path relative to the your current working directory see here:
[Getting path relative to the current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703281/getting-path-relative-to-the-current-working-directory)

**EDIT:** 
Can't comment as not enough reputation.
When you do a Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() what is the value that is returned?

If Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName returns the "Export" folder path you could just do this:

```
string fileName = "Calc.xlsx";        
workbook.Save(Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName, fileName );
```

Comment: I want to save it under Export folder. How can I do that? Thanks.