# ASP.net get files excluding root folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get the file path from a folder/subfolder inside a folder and populate it to a image attributes. using `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\StorageFolders");`will return full path and will return

> Not allowed to load local resource

.

So now i am using looping and replacement method. Am i doing i right?
or can i just get the full path excluding root folder
example :
the function returns

> C:\WebsiteRootFolder\Myfolder\SubFolderA\handsome.png

to relative

> Myfolder\SubFolderA\handsome.png

always return to the root folder of the website

```
 var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
        var rootpath= HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");

foreach (var item in fileList)
        {
            string s = item.Replace(rootpath, "");
            Image image = new Image();
            image.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl(@"~\"+ s);
            //continue of codes
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Access Denied:

You don't have a right `permission` to that particular folder. Make sure you have to change the permission to `full access` to that folder.

Comment: folder already full access. i reposted the error. the error is not because of permission. is how the website works which doesnt allow to access the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Path.GetFullPath method? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This will return full path. I Wan to return relative path.For example the path return c:/website/folderA/img.png
i only want it to return FolderA/img.png

Comment: sorry I misunderstood the question. would this help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/703292/2788979

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. i managed to replace the line with linq

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

i changed to

```
  var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => (new FileInfo(x).FullName.Replace(root, ""))).ToArray();
```