# How do I get the subdirectories in a folder without including the parent directory of said folder?

Tags: vb.net, subdirectory

I know that `IO.Directory.GetDirectories("X:/mydata/backup/stuff", "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)` works for getting all directories, but I need to figure out how to not have the parent half attached to each string.

I need the output to be:

- `stuff/that/was/backed/up/file0.ext`
- `stuff/that/was/backed/up/file1.ext`
- `stuff/that/was/backed/up/file3.ext`

Instead of:

- `X:/mydata/backup/stuff/that/was/backed/up/file0`
- etc.

The path can be anything, so I can't use a hard-coded solution either, like using `Split(path, "/", 2)` in the `Application.StartupPath` directory (which I currently use).

Comment: You didn't show what you mean by the parent half, but perhaps you are looking for `theFullPath.Replace(parentHalf, "")`.

Comment: I edited your question to make it easier to understand. Feel free to edit it further where you think is needed. One more thing, you do realize that `GetDirectories()` only returns the sub-directories and does **Not** include the files, right? Because you're using file paths in your output examples. If you need the files, you can use `GetFiles()` and if you need both the sub-directories and the files, you can use [`GetFileSystemEntries()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfilesystementries) instead.

Comment: I know that, I just used GetDirectories() in my example

Comment: Do you always want the last directory of "X:\mydata\backup\stuff" to be included in the "stuff\that\was\backed\up\file0.ext"? If so, what if there is no last directory, e.g. "X:\"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much hair pulling and completely unhelpful comments, I have found a solution:

```
Dim unitstring As String() = Split(TextBox2.Text, "\") 'separate directory names
Dim unitcount As Integer = Array.LastIndexOf(unitstring, Path.GetFileName(TextBox2.Text)) + 2 'get how far in the directory we are from the root. 
Dim paths As New List(Of String) 'list to hold results
For Each x In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(TextBox2.Text, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 'loop through all directories to get them in the format needed
    Dim pathsplit As String() = Split(x, "\", unitcount) 'split from parent
    paths.Add(pathsplit(unitcount - 1)) 'the last item in the array is what is needed.
Next
```

if anyone else needs code like this, feel free to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods in `System.IO.Path` to manipulate path strings.

To separate directory and filename:

```
Dim filenameAndExtension As String = Path.GetFileName(fullPath)
Dim directory As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath)
```

You can also use `Path.GetFileName(directory)` to get the last part of a directory path.

To combine directory and filename:

```
Dim fullPath As String = Path.Combine(directory, filenameAndExtension)
```

Comment: but I need to include the path from the selected folder to the file

Comment: I don't need the full path. If the selected folder is "foldername" and subfolders and files within were named "folder0, folder1, file0, file1" and there are files named "file2" and "file3" in the subfolder, I need to find the path from the selected folder to each subfolder and file.

i need "Path/to/file/or/folder/filename.txt", not "D:/data/stuff/path/to/file/or/folder/filename.txt" or "filename.txt".

Comment: If you want a relative path, see: [Getting path relative to the current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703281/getting-path-relative-to-the-current-working-directory).

Comment: I will post my working code, hopefully you can make heads or tails out of it

Comment: google link to current code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GweGr4MUCTjOTEmVhU2o1VMWMyYjnmiB

Comment: I plan on changing everything to an xml based system that encodes data to Base64 strings.

the first issue is the fact that if a user chooses a folder other than the hard coded folder in the application directory, it glitches out.

Comment: This seems to be a conceptual problem. Not a programming problem. Store the folder in a settings file an ini file or ask for it in the application and store it in the registry.

Comment: I created my own solution. It was programming, not conceptual.