# Get path of file relative to some directory in C#

Tags: c#, .net, path, filepath, relative-path

Let's say I have the following  path and base directory

```
string FileDirectory = "/tmp/simple";
string fullPath = "/tmp/simple/s1/s1.txt";
```

Then how do I find the path of `s1.txt` relative to `FileDirectory` without writing a loop?

ie; I want `s1/s1.txt` as the output.

This looks like the inverse of the [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0) operation.

Hence I did like

```
string relativePath  = fullPath.Substring(FileDirectory.Length, (fullPath.Length - FileDirectory.Length));
```

Is there any existing function to achieve the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting path relative to the current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703281/getting-path-relative-to-the-current-working-directory)

Comment: With that, I'm getting output  as 
`simple/s1/s1.txt`.
Which is different from `s1/s1.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `Path.GetRelativePath(...)`. Used like this:

```
string FileDirectory = "/tmp/simple";
string fullPath = "/tmp/simple/s1/s1.txt";

string result = Path.GetRelativePath(FileDirectory, fullPath);
// s1\s1.txt
```

To get the result with forward slash `/` instead, you can do a simple `Replace()` on the result:

```
result = result.Replace("\\", "/");
// s1/s1.txt
```