# Getting a file path relative to a particular directory

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there a nice way in the WinAPI to get a path relative to another path?  For example:

Have a list of paths relative to:

a\b\c\d

And I'd like to change them all to paths relative to

a\b\c

Is there a neat way to do this or should I get path parsing?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path

Comment: Well not a duplicate .. one is for C# and one is for Win32 ..

Comment: You didn't read the entire answers there I guess, here is a lazy link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path#answer-275740

Comment: Relevant answer there, but still that does not make this a redundant question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i know there is no such functionality in the windows API, but there is e.g. an [article on CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/fileanddirectorynaming/article.php/c263/) that provides that functionality.

*edit*:
I stand corrected, there is [PathRelativePathTo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773740%28VS.85%29.aspx) in the shell api as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path#answer-275740).

Comment: That's certainly very close.  Thanks very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way of doing this directly, but you might be able to do it in a couple of steps using [PathCommonPrefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773574%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [PathCombine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773571%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Otherwise, [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) may make it possible, eg with the `relative_path()` method.