# Will this method of making relative paths work?

Tags: c#, .net, path, uri, relative-path

Since .NET doesn't include an API to make relative paths, I've used Uri's `MakeRelativeUri` method instead.  This works, but I've encountered several cases in which it doesn't due to the fact the Uri is escaped.  So I've patched up that too:

```
public static string MakeRelativePath(string basePath, string tgtPath) {
    return
        Uri.UnescapeDataString(
            new Uri(basePath, UriKind.Absolute)
                .MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(tgtPath, UriKind.Absolute))
            .ToString()
        ).Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
}
```

This versions *seems* to work, but it leaves me feeling a little quesy: aren't there any valid local filesystem paths that this gratuitous unescaping might corrupt?

**Related:** [How to get relative path from absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path)
The answers to that question do not address the issue of unusual characters and escaping at all, and as such don't answer this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get relative path from absolute path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path)

Comment: @Eamon There are some good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path If it was me I'd go for the solution that P/Invokes to `PathRelativePathTo()`

Comment: Yeah, I see an answer that's also using Uri, though without escaping, i.e. borked.  P/Invoking; well, that's slow and platform-dependent, meaning you may run into x86/x64 issues, non-fulltrust issues, and of course things like silverlight/XNA don't necessarily support it.  It'd work, but it's not my first choice.

Comment: @Eamon I can see that. Me I'm Windows centric and so P/Invoking is fine. I don't see speed being an issue - you aren't going to be calling this inside your app's hot loop are you?!!

Comment: I have done something similar in a custom search indexer, but at just a few hundred thousand paths, it's probably not a large issue.  Still; it's nice not to have the worry in the first place.  Btw, does PathRelativePathTo do any I/O and/or normalization?  MSDN doesn't say.

Comment: `PathRelativePathTo` doesn't touch the file system so far as I am aware. It's purely text based. If you want to know how it's implemented you can always look at the Wine source code!

Comment: Thanks, I absolutely love little ideas like that!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of escaping, unescaping and replacing, you could just use the underlying algorithm used by `System.Uri` and the `PathDifference` method.  Here it is, recovered via Reflector and modified for slightly better readability.  It has also been modified to use backslashes for DOS-style paths instead of forward slashes for URIs, and the comparison is always case-insensitive.

```
static string PathDifference(string path1, string path2)
{
    int c = 0;  //index up to which the paths are the same
    int d = -1; //index of trailing slash for the portion where the paths are the same

    while (c < path1.Length && c < path2.Length)
    {
        if (char.ToLowerInvariant(path1[c]) != char.ToLowerInvariant(path2[c]))
        {
            break;
        }

        if (path1[c] == '\\')
        {
            d = c;
        }

        c++;
    }

    if (c == 0)
    {
        return path2;
    }

    if (c == path1.Length && c == path2.Length)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }


    System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    while (c < path1.Length)
    {
        if (path1[c] == '\\')
        {
            builder.Append(@"..\");
        }
        c++;
    }

    if (builder.Length == 0 && path2.Length - 1 == d)
    {
        return @".\";
    }

    return builder.ToString() + path2.Substring(d + 1);
}
```

The expectation for the inputs seems to be that if either path represents a directory, it must have a trailing backslash.  Obviously, the paths must be non-null as well.

Here are some example inputs and outputs... see if it meets your needs.

```
Path1                   Path2               Output
C:\test\path1\path2\    C:\test\            ..\..\
C:\test\path1\file      C:\test\            ..\
C:\test\path1\path2\    C:\                 ..\..\..\
C:\test\path1\path2\    D:\                 D:\
C:\test\path1\path2\    C:\test\path1\pathA ..\pathA
C:\test\                C:\test\    
C:\test\                C:\test\file        file
C:\test\file            C:\test\            .\
C:\test\path #1!\path2\ C:\test\            ..\..\
```

Comment: yeah, the trailing backslash thing is fairly inherent, if you think about it - the algo doesn't actually have access to the filesystem, right?

Comment: I'm not entirely comfortable lifting this via reflector - I'm not a copyright lawyer, and who knows what's OK...

Comment: Btw thanks for the effort, it's certainly an interesting approach!

Comment: ...and it shows that `Uri` isn't doing any kind of normalization, which is a little unfortunate here; e.g. comparing `C:\test\path1\path2\` to `C:\test\\path1\pathA` doesn't do what it should.  On the other hand, `C:\test\xy\..\path1\pathA` does work with the `MakeRelativeUri` above but not here...