# Getting the relative path from the full path

Tags: c#, path, relative-path

I have to get the path excluding the relative path from the full path,
say

The relative path is ,**C:\User\Documents\**

fullpath ,**C:\User\Documents\Test\Folder2\test.pdf**

I want to get only the path after the relative path i.e **\Test\Folder2\test.pdf**

how can i achieve this.

I am using C# as the programming language

Comment: In which programming language, shell etc.?

Comment: `C:\User\Documents\` cannot a relative path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get relative path from absolute path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not talking about relative, so i will call it partial path.
If you can be sure that the partial path is part of your full path its a simple string manipulation:

```
string fullPath = @"C:\User\Documents\Test\Folder2\test.pdf";
string partialPath = @"C:\User\Documents\";
string resultingPath = fullPath.Substring(partialPath.Length);
```

This needs some error checking though - it will fail when either fullPath or partialPath is null or both paths have the same length.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmmm, but what if the case is different?  Or one of the path uses short-names for its folders?  The more complete solution would be...

```
public static string GetRelativePath(string fullPath, string containingFolder,
    bool mustBeInContainingFolder = false)
{
    var file = new Uri(fullPath);
    if (containingFolder[containingFolder.Length - 1] != Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
        containingFolder += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    var folder = new Uri(containingFolder); // Must end in a slash to indicate folder
    var relativePath =
        Uri.UnescapeDataString(
            folder.MakeRelativeUri(file)
                .ToString()
                .Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
            );
    if (mustBeInContainingFolder && relativePath.IndexOf("..") == 0)
        return null;
    return relativePath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Jan's answer, you could create an extension method on the `string` class (or the `Path` class if you wanted) such as:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static string GetPartialPath(this string fullPath, string partialPath)
        {
            return fullPath.Substring(partialPath.Length)
        }
    }   
}
```

And then use:

```
using ExtensionMethods;
string resultingPath = string.GetPartialPath(partialPath);
```

I haven't tested that this extension method works, but it [should do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).