# ASP.net Get Path

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have

```
C:\Softwares\Test\ASPnetTest\Project11\Shared\Public\Images\
```

How to convert it to

```
Shared\Public\Images\
```

Thank you.

Comment: I am retrieving list of directories (physical path) and displaying them as logical paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want the path as used in a URL:**

You can use something like this (classes are valid in C# too): http://geekswithblogs.net/AlsLog/archive/2006/08/03/87032.aspx

```
Public Function MapURL(ByVal Path As String) As String
     Dim AppPath As String = _
     HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")
     Dim url As String = String.Format("~{0}" _
     , Path.Replace(AppPath, "").Replace("\", "/"))
     Return url
End Function
```

...To make it easy:

```
private static string MapUrl(string path)
{
    var appPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");
    return string.Format("~{0}", path.Replace(appPath, "").Replace("\\", "/"));
}
```

**If you want the folder, relative to your app's base path:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.physicalapplicationpath.aspx

`Request.PhysicalApplicationPath` will give you the `c:\softwares\test\aspnettest\project11` part.  Then you can get the relative part, see this answer here for that:

[How to get relative path from absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path)

Comment: Yes it is solved but please change your second line to:

return string.Format("~/{0}", path.Replace(appPath, "").Replace("\\", "/"));

Probably a typo. :)

Comment: I can't see any difference, what did you change/fix? :)

Comment: I changed "~{0}" to "~/{0}". I confirm.