# Is there an easy way to find the path route from one directory to another VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, filesystems, relative-path

Given that I have a file in path:

```
C:\Applications\General Utils\Assembly1\Assembly1\Bin\Debug\Assembly1.dll
```

and I am working in the following path:

```
C:\Applications\Under Development\App1\App1\
```

is there some easy way to find the dotted path route from the application to the assembly:

```
..\..\..\General Utils\Assembly1\Assembly1\Bin\Debug\Assembly1.dll
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get relative path from absolute path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.Uri uri1 = new Uri(@"C:\Applications\General Utils\Assembly1\Assembly1\Bin\Debug\Assembly1.dll");
System.Uri uri2 = new Uri(@"C:\Applications\Under Development\App1\App1\"); 
Uri relativeUri = uri2.MakeRelativeUri(uri1);
Console.WriteLine(relativeUri.ToString());
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Thanks that does the trick although the output is in 'URI' format not file system format ie forward slashes instead of backslashes and %20 instead of space

Comment: maybe you'll get the path in the good format with  Path.GetFullPath()