# MSBuild: How to get the relative path to a file, given an absolute one?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a situation where I have a bunch of **absolute** paths, and I would like to convert them to **relative** paths based on another directory with MSBuild. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <FromPath>$(Bar)</FromPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <AbsolutePaths Include="@(Foo)" Exclude="@(Baz)" />
    <PathsRelativeToBar Include="@(AbsolutePaths->'???')" /> <!-- What goes here? -->
</ItemGroup>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**edit:** I found a C#-based solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9065207/4077294) StackOverflow question, but I'm not sure how (or if  it's possible) to convert it to MSBuild.

Comment: If you have the absolute path and relative working directory path, this could help :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703281/getting-path-relative-to-the-current-working-directory

Comment: @mojorisinify Thanks for helping! I had seen that solution already. Unfortunately, I'm not really sure how I would translate that to MSBuild code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a native function in MSBuild called ["MakeRelative"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx#BKMK_MakeRelative)

Here is how you can use it.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.5" >
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Bar>c:\temp\msbuild-sample\2</Bar>
        <FromPath>$(Bar)</FromPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <AbsolutePaths Include="c:\temp\msbuild-sample\1\**\*.txt" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="Build">
        <ItemGroup>
            <PathsRelativeToBar Include="@(AbsolutePaths)">
                <!-- Here is the magic... we're adding a piece of metadata with the relative path -->
                <RelativePath>$([MSBuild]::MakeRelative($(FromPath), %(AbsolutePaths.FullPath)))</RelativePath>
            </PathsRelativeToBar>
        </ItemGroup>
        <Message Text="----- Absolute paths -----" />
        <Message Text="%(AbsolutePaths.FullPath)" />
        <Message Text="----- Relative paths (showing full path) -----" />
        <Message Text="%(PathsRelativeToBar.FullPath)" />
        <Message Text="----- Relative paths (relative to $(FromPath)) -----" />
        <Message Text="%(PathsRelativeToBar.RelativePath)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Here is a quick view of my current environment

```
C:\temp\msbuild-sample>dir /s /b

C:\temp\msbuild-sample\1
C:\temp\msbuild-sample\sample.build
C:\temp\msbuild-sample\1\1.1
C:\temp\msbuild-sample\1\1.txt
C:\temp\msbuild-sample\1\2.txt
C:\temp\msbuild-sample\1\1.1\3.txt
C:\temp\msbuild-sample\1\1.1\4.txt
```

and here is the output.

```
----- Absolute paths -----
c:\temp\msbuild-sample\1\1.1\3.txt
c:\temp\msbuild-sample\1\1.1\4.txt
c:\temp\msbuild-sample\1\1.txt
c:\temp\msbuild-sample\1\2.txt
----- Relative paths (showing full path) -----
c:\temp\msbuild-sample\1\1.1\3.txt
c:\temp\msbuild-sample\1\1.1\4.txt
c:\temp\msbuild-sample\1\1.txt
c:\temp\msbuild-sample\1\2.txt
----- Relative paths (relative to c:\temp\msbuild-sample\2) -----
..\1\1.1\3.txt
..\1\1.1\4.txt
..\1\1.txt
..\1\2.txt
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Awesome, very helpful answer! I never knew about that function.