# changing absolute Path to relative Path

Tags: c#

How i would like to change my absolute Path to relative Path.
anyone can help?
this is my Code

```
string activeDirectory = @"X:\Temp\";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(activeDirectory);
foreach (string fileName in files)
{
   .....
}
```

Comment: change how?  You want a string holding the relative path?

Comment: Take a look at this. One of the first google results too, you should always try that first. http://softwareblog.alcedo.com/post/2010/02/24/Resolving-relative-paths-in-C.aspx

Comment: Try the solution suggested [here], seems to be what you requested.

[here]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer `files.Select(f => f.Substring(activeDirectory.Length))`.
That means 'Skip x chars and return the rest'.