# wrong image path save in sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i am new to asp.net c# somehow i am able to save image in folder and it's path in sql, but the code is saving the full path which is incorrect.[image]

below is the sql table picture.

my code is

```
con.Open();
if (Image.HasFile) {
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(Image.PostedFile.FileName);
    String ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Image.FileName);
    string filesize = Image.FileBytes.Length.ToString();

    if (ext.ToLower() == ".JPG" || ext.ToLower() == ".jpg" || ext.ToLower() == ".PNG" || ext.ToLower() == ".png" || ext.ToLower() == ".GIF" || ext.ToLower() == ".gif") {
        string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Posts/") + filename;
        Image.SaveAs(filepath);
        string qry1 = "insert into Images(Image_Name,Image_Size,Image_Path)values('" + filename + "','" + filesize + "','" + filepath + "')";
        SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand(qry1, con);
        cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } else if (ext.ToLower() == ".mp4" || ext.ToLower() == ".MP4" || ext.ToLower() == ".mpeg" || ext.ToLower() == ".MPEG" || ext.ToLower() == ".AVI" || ext.ToLower() == ".avi") {
        string filepathv = Server.MapPath("~/Posts/videos/" + filename);
        Image.SaveAs(filepathv);
        string qry1 = "insert into videos(Video_Name,Video_Size,Video_Path)values('" + filename + "','" + filesize + "','" + filepathv + "')";
        SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand(qry1, con);
        cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, use `SqlParamter` to avoid Sql injection, you should find a lot about this on stackoverflow: [How does SQLParameter prevent SQL Injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4892205/2630261)

Second, `Server.MapPath` returns the complete mapped file path, absolute to your hosting enviornment. It seems that you currently host every thing in an *IIS Express* (starting the project with `F5/Start`). To get the relative path you need the path of the base directory for your images/videos. Take a look at [How to get relative path from absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/340454/2630261). You only need to specify your working directory. For example `C:\inetpub\your-project\`. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**
If you want to use your working directory for calculating a relative path, try to use: [Environment.CurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving the file extension and use `ToLower()` but you compare it to the uppercase variant? Also use the parameters for SqlCommand.

```
con.Open();
if (Image.HasFile) {
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(Image.PostedFile.FileName);
    String ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Image.FileName);
    string filesize = Image.FileBytes.Length.ToString();
    string qry1;
    string dir;

    if (ext.ToLower() == ".jpg" || ext.ToLower() == ".png" || ext.ToLower() == ".gif") {
        dir = "Posts/";
        qry1 = "insert into Images(Image_Name, Image_Size, Image_Path) values (@fn, @fs, @fp)";

    } else if (ext.ToLower() == ".mp4" || ext.ToLower() == ".mpeg" || ext.ToLower() == ".avi") {
        dir = "Posts/videos/";
        qry1 = "insert into videos(Video_Name, Video_Size, Video_Path) values (@fn, @fs, @fp)";
    }
    string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/" + dir + filename);
    Image.SaveAs(filepath);

    SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand(qry1, con);
    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fn", filename);
    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fs", filesize);
    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fp", filepath);
    cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```