# How do I get the path to the parent directory as relative path

Tags: c#, path

Just now I have a path like this `MyDir\Inner\Foo` and I want to be able to transform it into `MyDir\Inner`.

My idea was to use `Path.Combine(myRelativeDir, "..")` and then (for user display purposes) resolve it to remove the `..`.

When I've researched this online, I can only seem to find solutions that involve doing a `Path.GetFullPath` after `Path.Combine` to resolve it, but this does not help me as it results in something like `C:\RootFolders\ThatIWantToHide\MyDir\Inner` and I don't want to show a full path.

Is there anything in the standard libraries that allows this or will I have to resort to string manipulation of some sort?

**In summary**

Input:
`MyDir\Inner\Foo` (relative path)

Desired Output:
`MyDir\Inner` (relative path maintained)

Undesired Output:
`C:\RootFolders\ThatIWantToHide\MyDir\Inner` (relative path lost)

Undesired Output:
`Inner` (just the name, not the relative path)

Comment: I might be missing something but looks like you need [Directory.GetParent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx)

Comment: Hi Vlad, I just gave it a shot but it still seems to return an absolute path. https://dotnetfiddle.net/IBK6Ba

Comment: Please check my answer. You can access Name property, which returns a relative path. FullName has an absolute one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets the parent and maintains relative path info:

```
 Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(@".\bin\debug"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Path.GetFullPath to get the absolute path, and than use the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path) to change it to a relative path. In short, the code uses Uri.MakeRelativeUri() method.