# How to convert the element's reference file absolute path to relative path in Revit api

Tags: c#, revit-api

i get the revit element's reference files, and then i want to convert the reference file absolute path to relative path.How to convert? ths!
The code as follow:

```
Uri uriRoot = new Uri(AnaysisResultRootFolder);

foreach (ElementId elementId in elementIds)
{
    ExternalFileReference externalFileReference = 
      transmissionData.GetLastSavedReferenceData(elementId);
    ExternalFileReferenceType fileReferenceType = 
      externalFileReference.ExternalFileReferenceType;

    if (fileReferenceType == ExternalFileReferenceType.RevitLink)
    {
        ModelPath referenceModelPath = externalFileReference.GetAbsolutePath();
        //d:\doc\sub1.rvt
        string referenceFilePath = ModelPathUtils.ConvertModelPathToUserVisiblePath(
          referenceModelPath); 
        string relativeFilePath = "../Reference/sub1.rvt";
    }
}
```

I don't know how to convert "d:\doc\reference\sub1.rvt" to "./reference/sub1.rvt"

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/340454/1300049

Answer (score 0):

Its called RELATIVE !so you should know the relation between Your current Location and You desired Location!