# C# winforms get nth folders from path

Tags: c#, winforms, path

I've got an absolute path available to me. Say: `C:/Program/CoreFiles/Folder1/Folder2/File.txt`.

I need to copy that file to `C:/Program/Projects/ProjectName/` but it needs to keep `Folder1/Folder2/File.txt` intact. So the end result should be `C:/Program/Projects/ProjectName/Folder1/Folder2/File.txt`.

My first attempt at solving this was to try and get the relative path between 2 absolute paths. Found [Path.GetRelativePath(string, string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getrelativepath?view=netcore-3.1) which obviously didn't help as it wasn't meant for WinForms. It would mess up anyway as the final result would be `C:/Program/Projects/ProjectName/CoreFiles/Folder1/Folder2/File.txt`.

The target directory is empty and I don't know the relative path to copy beforehand other than somehow getting that info out of the absolute path. Since `File.Copy` won't create folders that don't exist yet, I need to create them first. So how do I get the path that leads up to the file from the `CoreFiles` directory out of the absolute path?

The only working solution I can come up with is using regex to just replace `CoreFiles` with `Projects/ProjectName` in the path string and work with that. But that somehow seems the wrong approach.

Comment: `Directory.CreateDirectory()` does build nested paths. You could use the Uri class and get the `Segments`, skipping Directory names until you find the one you want to start from (`CoreFiles`). Then use `Path.Combine` to rebuild the destination path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't use `Path.GetRelativePath`. I suggest looking at another answer that describes how to do this yourself. 
Like here...

- [How to get relative path from absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/340454/1812944)

Using the method in that answer, you can do the rest of your task as shown below.

```cs
string sourcePath = "C:/Program/CoreFiles/Folder1/Folder2/File.txt";
string sourceRoot = "C:/Program/CoreFiles/";
string destinationRoot = "C:/Program/Projects/ProjectName/";

// Use built-in .NET Path.GetRelativePath if you can. Otherwise use a custom function. Like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/340454/1812944
string relativePath = MakeRelativePath(sourceRoot, sourcePath);

// Combine the paths, and make the directory separators all the same. 
string destinationPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(destinationRoot, relativePath));

// Create nested folder structure for your files. 
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(destinationPath));

// Copy the file over. 
File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);
```