# Why Get A Relative Path From One To Another Working Not Correct?

Tags: c#, .net, file, filepath

guys i tried this one:

**current: `\netcoreapp2.1\ResultPath`**

**target : `\netcoreapp2.1\ReportPath\report1`**

```
   AssemblyDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

   Uri currentPath = new Uri(AssemblyDirectory + "//ResultPath");
   Uri targetPath = new Uri(reportsSubDir);

   Uri relPath = currentPath.MakeRelativeUri(targetPath);
```

In result i'm getting

```
relPath.OriginalString = ReportPath/report1
```

Why is not ../ReportPath/report1 ?

And now for example:

if i have

**current: `\netcoreapp2.1\ResultPath\Test`**

**target : `\netcoreapp2.1\ReportPath\report1`**

I'm getting **correct** result in this way

```
relPath.OriginalString = ../../ReportPath/report10
```

Could anyone explain me why in first step i'm getting bad Relative Path, but in second good

and any idea how can i fix it, if i want to use first and second examples in my way ?

Comment: @Liam string AssemblyDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

Comment: any explanation in bellow why it needs a slash ?

Comment: I don't know any other way to find Relative Path From one to another Path

Comment: I think you actually want this: [How to get relative path from absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/how-to-get-relative-path-from-absolute-path)

Comment: And in future it could be any other Directory Path :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you are using .NET 5, you're in luck, since new method was included: [`Path.GetRelativePath(string, string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getrelativepath?view=net-5.0)

If not, we can always dig into MS .NET Framework code:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Workflow.ComponentModel/AuthoringOM/Design/DesignerHelpers.cs,a561eb779ce7163d

And copy implementation, which is:

```
static class PathHelper
 {
     internal static string GetRelativePath(string pathFrom, string pathTo)
     {
         Uri uri = new Uri(pathFrom);
         string relativePath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(pathTo)).ToString());
         relativePath = relativePath.Replace(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
         if (!relativePath.Contains(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()))
             relativePath = "." + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + relativePath;
         return relativePath;
     }
 }
```

Usage then would be:

```
var p1 = @"C:\users\turek\source\";
var p2 = @"C:\users\turek\desktop\";

PathHelper.GetRelativePath(p1, p2);
// returns "..\\desktop\\"
```

Comment: `Path.GetRelativePath` was introduced in .Net Core 2.0 not .Net 5

Comment: @Liam But it's in NET 5 as well :)

Answer (score -1):

Found answer added  /  to current Path it looks like ::

```
Uri currentPath = new Uri(AssemblyDirectory + "//ResultPath/");
```

Still need explanation :)